# Cannot trap undefined error in input form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Using parse.com and javascript/jquery.

The below code should capture the input from the user in the "friendsearch" input box.

Once the submit button is clicked, it should query the parse.com backend and find out if the user exists. At the moment I keep getting "undefined" returned in "friendName" which I cannot spot why or what is causing the error?

```
  <form class="Find Friend">

        <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
        <input type="text" id="friendsearch" placeholder="Find Friend" class="input-field" required/> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login">Find</button> 
</form>
```

---

```
var friendName;

$('#friendsearch').on('keyup', function(e) {
   friendName = $(this).val();
});

var friendFinder = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", friendName);  // find users that match
query.find({
success: function(friend) {
alert(friendName); 
  },
    error: function (error) {
 //Show if no user was found to match

 alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
     }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I revised your code so that the friendName variable actually contains the contents of the input box on your form.  The problem was that your original code was trying to get access to the contents of your input box before it was even loaded into the DOM.

Try this for your HTML:

```
<form class="Find Friend">
        <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
        <input type="text" id="friendsearch" placeholder="Find Friend" class="input-field" /> 
        <button id="find_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-login">Find</button> 
</form>
```

And this for your javascript:

```
var friendName;

function findFriend(){
    friendName = $('#friendsearch').val();
    alert(friendName);

    var friendFinder = Parse.Object.extend("_User");

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("username", friendName);  // find users that match
    query.find({
    success: function(friend) {
    alert(friendName); 
      },
        error: function (error) {
     //Show if no user was found to match

     alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
         }

    });   
}

$('#find_button').click(function(e){
    findFriend();
});
```

I updated the live jsFiddle example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/LWA48/2/

In the jsFiddle example, the Parse object prints {"error": "Please use POST request"} when you click the button, but at least your friendName variable contains the name you typed in the box!  Hopefully, this can take you the rest of the way.

Comment: thanks so much! been trying to solve this for over a week! All front end works, but I'm getting a parse -1 error message on sumbitting, but I think this needs to be logged under a different question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is where you're assigning friendName = $(this).val();

Try using e.target to get a reference to the value currently in the text input box.  I'm not sure if it's e.target off the top of my head but I'm fairly certain that you want a property contained inside the e argument.

Try $(e.target).val() or $(e.currentTarget).val() something like that instead of $(this).val();

What I also like to do when I'm trying to figure out why something isn't being set properly is to set a breakpoint in the chrome debugger.  In this case, you can put 'debugger' in your code where you want the browser to break on.  So in your example, you could write this:

```
$('#friendsearch').on('keyup', function(e) {
    debugger
    friendName = $(this).val();
});
```

And in your Chrome Dev Tools you can inspect the value of e and determine what properties and values are available.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the tip re debugger, as yet I've still not been able to resolve the issue...

Comment: I made a jsFiddle of your code here:  [http://jsfiddle.net/LWA48/](http://jsfiddle.net/LWA48/)

When I type inside the text box, the value of friendName is assigned.  Where exactly are you finding it 'undefined' at?

Comment: thanks, you can see what I mean here http://kudosoo.com/findfriends5.html try searching for a user called "dave"